# Borderlands 2 FPS drop

Tags: borderlands-2, framerate

I have been playing *Borderlands 2* for about 200 hours. A few weeks ago, however, I bought a new PC. Now the game's framerate drops down to around 20 FPS.

PC Specs:

- **CPU:** Intel i7 4790k (5GHz)
- **GPU:** 2x Asus Poseidon GTX 980 (SLI)
- **RAM:** Corsair Vengeance 64 GB Pro 2400MHz
- **OS:** Windows 8.1

I didn't have such issues on my old PC, which had an EVGA GTX 570 HD graphics card. Can't remember the rest of the specs on that one, though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd try disabling SLI and compare the performance.  Some games have issues with SLI.

Comment: Will check it in a few min :) will see how it goes.

Comment: Nope, droping even lower now.

Comment: You sure it's a Borderlands only issue?

Comment: Drop that insane overclock. 5GHz. is pushing the envelope in stability on that CPU. Do you run the latest NVidia drivers? Reinstall those first to avoid any issues on that part. 

Using Afterburner/Riva OSD to monitor, what is your CPU speeds/usage/temps as well as GPU usage during game play? <

Comment: Likely a PhysX problem. Set it to low, [says a guy with your specs](https://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/620712364041409779/).

Answer (score 0):

By doing a quick search (not sure this will fix your problem). This person does not have the same specs as your computer but maybe these could fix your lag spikes?

```
[Engine.Engine]

//PhysXGpuHeapSize=128

//PhysXMeshCacheSize=8

PhysXGpuHeapSize=256

PhysXMeshCacheSize=16



[SystemSettings]

//Fullscreen=False

//WindowedFullscreen=True

Fullscreen=True

WindowedFullscreen=False



[MemoryBudgets]


//AnimationMB=15

//AudioMB=10

//CodeMB=30

//LevelObjectsMB=4

//TerrainMB=4

//GameDataMB=3

//MaterialMB=1

//ParticleMB=5

//PhysicsMB=10

//ScaleformMB=8

//ShadersMB=10

//SkelMeshMB=2

//StaticMeshMB=10

//TextureMB=120

AnimationMB=32

AudioMB=16

CodeMB=64

LevelObjectsMB=16

TerrainMB=16

GameDataMB=16

MaterialMB=16

ParticleMB=16

PhysicsMB=32

ScaleformMB=32

ShadersMB=32

SkelMeshMB=16

StaticMeshMB=32

TextureMB=256
```

The above settings basically double the resource settings devoted to PhysX, as well as one setting for using Fullscreen mode. Windowed full screen mode costs some frames, so using fullscreen mode should net some extra FPS (I get around 15 FPS more using it alone). The above settings smoothed out my FPS to a steady 60 even in fairly high combat areas. The only area I currently have a problem with is one many others are as well, and that is the final area of the DLC "Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep".

This fixed the lag issue for another person on Steam Forums. His reply is:

Thanks for the clarification. Lath's tweak worked out well though, I'm getting much better framerates in areas that were previously trouble spots.

If this does not fix your problem, you can always try to delete your .ini files in your /Documents/My Games/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/Config and re-do your settings. I reccomend starting on everything very low/low and then work your graphics up until you it achieves a stable fps.

Sources:

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3147700

PS. This is mostly copy paste from the link..